# meaning of nonce=`$CURL -s "http://${server}:${port}/${manager}" | grep nonce | grep "${balancer}" | sed "s/.*nonce=\(.*\)['\"].*/\1/"

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to disable nodes from apache loadbalancer using shell script. I got some idea online but I am not able to understand piece of code written for disabling the nodes form loadbalancer. Below is the code I am referring:

```
disable() {
  balancer=$1
  worker=$2
  if [ -z "$balancer" ] || [ -z "$worker" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [-s host] [-p port] [-m balancer-manager]  disable  balancer_name  worker_route"
    echo "  balancer_name :    balancer/cluster name"
    echo "  worker_route  :    worker route e.g.)"
    exit 1
  fi
  
  echo "Disabling $2 of $1..."
  nonce=`$CURL -s "http://${server}:${port}/${manager}" | grep nonce | grep "${balancer}" | sed "s/.*nonce=\(.*\)['\"].*/\1/" | tail -n 1`
  if [ -z "$nonce" ]; then
    echo "balancer_name ($balancer) not found"
    exit 1
  fi
```

Can you please help me understand the meaning of above mentioned code. Especially, about **nonce**.

Answer (score 0):

Picking apart your command, you probably first need to understand how pipes work in Unix. Each command has standard input and standard output; the notation `first | second` is a pipeline where the standard output from `first` becomes the standard *input* for `second`; so instead of `first` printing anything, or `second` reading something from a file, we pass whatever `first` would print as the input for `second`.

- `nonce=...` assigns `...` to the variable `nonce`. The name suggests this is intended to be used as a [cryptographic nonce.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)
- `` `cmd` `` is an obsolescent synonym for `$(cmd)`. This [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) replaces (substitutes) the command `cmd` with its output. So the value of `nonce` will be whatever this subshell prints to standard output.
- `$CURL` is probably going to run `curl`, but we can only guess. Usually you would make sure `curl` is on your `PATH` and simply use the literal command `curl`.
- `curl -s http://whatever` fetches the contents of the URL and prints them to standard output. The `-s` option suppresses any status messages. The output gets piped to ...
- `grep nonce`, which prints to standard output any line which contains a match of the regular expression `nonce` (which simply matches this text verbatim anywhere on a line) and suppresses all others; which then gets piped to ...
- `grep "${balancer}"` which similarly prints only lines which match whatever regular expression the variable `balancer` contains (the braces are harmless but useless); which then gets piped to ...
- `sed "s/.*nonce=\(.*\)['\"].*/\1/"` which picks out the stuff between the parentheses -- anything up to the last single or double quote after `nonce=`; which then gets piped to ...
- `tail -n 1` which discards all lines except the last one.

So in summary, pick out the last occurrence of `nonce=` from the content behind the remote URL, and print that, but only up to just before the first single or double quote.

This is all rather clumsy and inefficient; any pipe involving multiple `grep` and `sed` commands should probably be refactored to a simple Awk script.

```sh
    nonce=$(curl -s "http://${server}:${port}/${manager}" |
        awk -v b="$balancer" '/nonce/ && $0 ~ b {
            sub(/^.*nonce=/, ""); sub(/[\047\042][^\047\042]*$/, ""); n=$0 }
          END { print n }')
```

The `sed` command in particular looks slightly obscure; normally, we would expect the output we want to extract to be *between* quotes, but this extracts up to just before the last single or double quote.  The command `sed -n 's/.*\(stuff\).*/\1/p'` would be the normal way to only print the lines from which we actually managed to extract `stuff`.  But without seeing what the URL contains, we can only speculate about whether this is correct or not. Certainly the conventional syntax would have allowed the author to omit the first `grep` entirely.

Getting the last `nonce` is probably just a guardrail to make sure there is never more than one; I would assume we would normally expect only a single match.

`grep`, `sed`, and Awk all operate on regular expressions. If you are new to regex, perhaps visit [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) and check out the list of learning resources near the end.

Going forward, probably try https://explainshell.com/ before asking for human assistance.